# Measuring weather impact on sales as a crossed random effect

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, seasonality, fourier-transform

I'm trying to model sales of a clothing brand having longitudinal data (unbalanced panel: 20 stores with 50 - 157 weeks of datapoints).

There are many regressors in my analysis, but I believe that weather is one of the most important ones as the brand offers typical winter clothes between December and February, beach/summer ones between June and August and all-season clothes during the whole year.

The correlation between total sales and temperature is high (~0,64), but I have a problem with the "reciprocal seasonality": it is obvious that sales decrease during the cold Summer, but so they should in case of warm Winter (the correlation between sales and weather in Winter is negative).

I have decided to go for a mixed model as I'm using many variables and believe that some of them are important on the store level. However, I have a problem with implementing the weather effect that  depends on a season. My current solution is to add a `temperature | season` crossed effect so the model looks like this:

```
lmer <- lmer(sales ~ other.variables + temperature + 
               (some.variables | store) + (temperature | season), 
     data = data)
```

After doing some research I've decided to use crossed effects, as I don't think that seasons are nested within stores (please correct me if I'm wrong).

EDIT:

Season may be a month or even ISO week (number of week within a year, usually 1 - 52). However, I believe that using ISO weeks may lead to overfitting, so the seasons should be somehow predefined - for example first two weeks of each year will be labeled as "Early Winter", next three ones as "Winter Peak" , "Early Spring" and so on.

sales are measured on the weekly level per store. We believe that sales depend on price, distribution and temperature.

```
   store       week sales price distributiom       season temperature
1      A 2017-01-02    10   1.1          0.7 Early Winter         -10
2      A 2017-01-09     7   1.1          0.7 Early Winter         -11
3      A 2017-01-16     8   1.2          0.8  Winter Peak          -2
4    ...        ...   ...   ...          ...          ...         ...
5      A 2018-01-01    12   0.9         0.25 Early Winter          -4
6      A 2018-01-08    10   1.2          0.5 Early Winter          -3
7      A 2018-01-15     8   1.1          0.8  Winter Peak          -7
8    ...        ...   ...   ...          ...          ...         ...
9      B 2017-01-02    11   1.1          0.9 Early Winter          -7
10     B 2017-01-09    12   1.2          0.8 Early Winter          -8
11     B 2017-01-16     7   0.7          0.7  Winter Peak          -9
12   ...        ...   ...   ...          ...          ...         ...
13     B 2018-01-01    10   0.9          0.9 Early Winter         -10
14     B 2018-01-08    12   1.2          0.7 Early Winter          -7
15     B 2018-01-15    11   1.1          0.8  Winter Peak          -5
```

Of course, there are more stores, more weeks and more seasons.

So, to keeps things simple, let's assume that price and distribution do not vary across stores. However, I am interested in the temperature effect on sales that should be dependant on the season.

After some more reading [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/119728/mixed-effects-model-with-repeated-measures/119750) I'm even more confused and consider treating the season as a fixed effect, so I'm considering three models:

```
lmer1 <- lmer(sales ~ price + distribution + temperature + 
               (1 | store) + (temperature | season), 
     data = data)
```

```
lmer2 <- lmer(sales ~ price + distribution + temperature + 
               (1 | store) + ( 0 + temperature | season), 
     data = data)
```

```
lmer3 <- lmer(sales ~ price + distribution + temperature*season + 
               (1 | store), 
     data = data)
```

Which of them is the best pick for the described problem?

Is it correct if I interpret the results of these models like below:

lmer1: the average effect of temperature on sales is B * temperature, but if it is Early Winter, the additional effect is (B_early_winter) * temperature. Each season will also get its own effect on the global Intercept.

lmer2: the average effect of temperature on sales is B * temperature, but if it is Early Winter, the additional effect is (B_early_winter) * temperature.

lmer3: each season and season:temperature effect will be a separate parameter.

Comment: What is the temporal resolution of your *sales* variable? Do you measure it daily, weekly or monthly?

Comment: The data is aggregated to weeks. However, I have an access to the daily data (sales, temperature per store), so the temperature in each week is a weighted mean (daily temperature x sales share of the given day in the week).

Comment: You mention that season may be a month or even ISO week. I don't know what ISO means, but how do you have it measured in the model you showed us?

Comment: ISO week is the number of week within a year (typically 1 - 52). However, I'm afraid of overfitting while using so many timepoints. My data has a panel structure, sales of each shop is measured for 50-157 weeks. I am thinking of aggregating these  weeks to "seasons" - like months or, for example, "early winter" for first 2 weeks of the year, "peak winter" for next 3 ones and so on and use them as a crossed random effect for temperature.

Comment: For example - imagine there are just to stores, A and B, both with   sales data for 2 years, 104 weeks. Adding seasons will not change the data structure, but will add "season labels" for weeks within years, so the First two weeks of each year will be labeled as "early winter", for example - and so on.

Comment: Maybe you need to give a broad overview of your data. How many rows, what variables, what do they mean, how many levels (if factor) etc. Based on the information it is hard to give you proper feedback. Because your question is data related.

Comment: Thank you, Toby, I edited the question. I know the task is pretty complicated, usually Fixed Effects models are enough to cope with such models, however the weather does complicate things in this case.